# Why is only the text clickable in this div?

Tags: html, css, button

I am trying to create a div that is a button by putting an anchor inside a div.

HTML

```
<div class="div1" style="width:300px;">
    <a href="#">hello</a>                        
</div>
```

CSS

```
.div1 {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    margin:5px;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #494949 !important;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/BzFyS/

I think it is not working because osomething simple I am missing with positioning.  Any tips?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way: add this `css`:

```
.div1 a {
    display: block;
}
```

That's it.

If you want the whole `div` be clickable (including the `padding` area):

```
.div1 {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    margin:5px;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding:0px; /* set to 0 */
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #494949 !important;
}
.div1 a {
    display: block;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BzFyS/2/

Answer (score 2):

If you want the whole div to be clickable, you may do this :

HTML

```
<div id="div1" style="width:300px;">
    <a href="#">hello</a>                        
</div>
```

CSS

```
#div1 {
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
    margin:5px;
    border-width:5px;
    border-style:solid;
    padding:10px;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #494949 !important; /* do you really need that ? */
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('div1').onclick=function(){
      // do something
}
```

But then you don't really need the `a` element.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/JyDpw/)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add to your CSS:

```
.div1 a {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the tags around the div like this:

```
<a href="#"><div class="div1" style="width:300px;">
    <p>hello</p>                    
</div></a>
```

This will work.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want this div to be a "button" yes?

The simple solution is to define the size of the `<a>` by using padding and `display: block;`

you can still define the colors, margins, and position of the `<div>`... but the clickable area is in the `<a>`